# how read file json in the solution Windows 10?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

I am trying read a file json within solution, but is not working.

this file

[image: File Json]

this my code

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<DtoTemas>> ListarTemas()
            {
                string jsonResult = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    string filename = "TemasApi.json";
                    var pasta = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

                    StorageFile file = await pasta.GetFileAsync(filename);                

                    jsonResult = await StorageFileHelper.StorageFileToTextAsync(file);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }


                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DtoTemas>>(jsonResult);
            }
```

When application is running, it load file

[image: File Json Read]

but it not serializer to object

[image: Error]

Comment: The class representing your json is not a list. It is an object containing a *List of DtoTemas*

Comment: but in this case I wanted a list,I created this json file, how I do to be a list?

Comment: `yourObj.DtoTemas` is your list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wrapper model to match the JSON structure you are deserializing:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DtoTemas[] DtoTemas { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize to this model:

```
var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonResult);
return model.DtoTemas;
```

The reason for that is because your JSON doesn't represent an `IEnumerable<DtoTemas>` like what you were trying to deserialize to but rather an object that has a property called `DtoTemas` that represents the collection you are looking for.

If you want this to work:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DtoTemas>>(jsonResult);
```

then your file must look like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Nome": "Bing",
        "NomeBuscaNaApi": "",
        "NomeResource": "Bing",
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Nome": "Personalizado",
        "NomeBuscaNaApi": "",
        "NomeResource": "Personalizado",
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: I tryied too :/ but not work

`try
            {
                var objeto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DtoTemas>>(jsonResult);
                return objeto;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }`

Comment: Did you update the JSON as shown in my answer? If you want `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DtoTemas>>(jsonResult)‌​` to work then your JSON should look as shown in my answer and not as you currently have. Please read more carefully and try `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonResult)‌​` where `MyModel` definition is shown in my answer.

Comment: So if you have updated the JSON so that it represents an array of objects then `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DtoTemas>>(jsonResult)‌​` should work. To validate that your JSON is correct put it into http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: the file: [File Json](https://github.com/marcoslcosta/WindowsPhoneSamples/issues/1)

Comment: The result of the site is: Valid JSON. :/

Comment: Make sure that the `jsonResult` string variable that you are passing to the `DeserializeObject` method contains the proper file contents (the one you have put into http://jsonlint.com/ and ensured that its valid JSON). Maybe you are getting some exception reading the file contents even before attempting to deserialize it.

Comment: In the Visual Studio, appear an option <No Schema Selected>. 

I need to select this option?

Comment: the result is: Json invalid !! \o/ I may have to put a utf-8 encoding